# JavaScript spam filter

Tags: javascript

I tried to make a spam filter for my e-mail by JavaScript. Unfortunately the code won't be passed by a validator. Can anyone say what are the mistakes in my code in http://jaakkospage.comyr.com/ ?

```
If you want to contact, please send me an
<script type="text/javascript">
// Email obfuscator script 2.1 by Tim Williams, University of Arizona
// Random encryption key feature by Andrew Moulden, Site Engineering Ltd
// This code is freeware provided these four comment lines remain intact
// A wizard to generate this code is at http://www.jottings.com/obfuscator/
{ coded = "sppDD0.s.fBxxpYp@ULpJY.Q0L?fjHsBQi=LpJY 5m0L iVB cBHxpUB"
  key = "r3uREWBMXSnIezJANyZHi2Dq8btKkGv7PQFd4VTc51xh9wf0pCLYsoaUmljO6g"
  shift=coded.length
  link=""
  for (i=0; i<coded.length; i++) {
    if (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))==-1) {
      ltr = coded.charAt(i)
      link += (ltr)
    }
    else {     
      ltr = (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))-shift+key.length) % key.length
      link += (key.charAt(ltr))
    }
  }
document.write("<a href='mailto:"+link+"'>e-mail.</a>")
}
//-->
</script><noscript>Sorry, you need Javascript on to email me.</noscript>
```

Some of the [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjaakkospage.comyr.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0):

> Line 42, Column 27: character ";" not
>   allowed in attribute specification
>   list
>
> ```
> for (i=0; i<coded.length; i++) {
> ```
>
> Line 42, Column 27: element
>   "coded.length" undefined
>
> ```
> for (i=0; i<coded.length; i++) {
> ```
>
> You have used the element named
>   above in your document, but the
>   document type you are using does not
>   define an element of that name. This
>   error is often caused by:
>
> incorrect use of the "Strict" document
>   type with a document that uses frames
>   (e.g. you must use the "Frameset"
>   document type to get the ""
>   element), by using vendor proprietary
>   extensions such as "" or
>   "" (this is usually fixed by
>   using CSS to achieve the desired
>   effect instead). by using upper-case
>   tags in XHTML (in XHTML attributes and
>   elements must be all lower-case).

Comment: Maybe because it does not exist? But seriously - can you paste snippet please?

Comment: Erm, you have to show us the code before we can tell you what your mistake was.

Comment: Link to code? Might be better to architect a web service that uses a proven backend like SpamAssassin/ClamAV and call that from your Javascript application?

Comment: Not without really really a lot more info.  E.g. your code, the output from the validator, etc.  Also note that this validator checks for valid markup (e.g. HTML), not javascript.  If you want to "validate" your javascript you might want to look at jslint (http://www.jslint.com/).

Comment: When you run your pages through the validator of w3c (which you said you used), it tells you exactly what's wrong with it.

Comment: It works for me, I get jaakko.j.seppala@gmail.com in my E-Mail client when clicking the link.

Comment: Hey, don't everyone pile on the newcomer. Yes, he didn't provide enough information, but it's been 4 minutes since he posted this question, and he already has 3 close votes and a downvote. Maybe people should wait until he's had a chance to edit his question, if he just pasted the wrong link in by accident..

Comment: Why was this closed as not a real question?  Maybe it wasn't phrased in the best way, but it's a legitimate question.  Instead of closing, work with him to phrase it differently.

Comment: I'm sorry. <script type="text/javascript">
// Email obfuscator script 2.1 by Tim Williams, University of Arizona
// Random encryption key feature by Andrew Moulden, Site Engineering Ltd
// This code is freeware provided these four comment lines remain intact
// A wizard to generate this code is at http://www.jottings.com/obfuscator/
{ coded = "sppDD0.s.fBxxpYp@ULpJY.Q0L?fjHsBQi=LpJY 5m0L iVB cBHxpUB"
  key = "r3uREWBMXSnIezJANyZHi2Dq8btKkGv7PQFd4VTc51xh9wf0pCLYsoaUmljO6g"
  shift=coded.length
  link=""

Comment: for (i=0; i<coded.length; i++) {
    if (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))==-1) {
      ltr = coded.charAt(i)
      link += (ltr)
    }
    else {     
      ltr = (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))-shift+key.length) % key.length
      link += (key.charAt(ltr))
    }
  }
document.write("<a href='mailto:"+link+"'>e-mail.</a>")
}
//-->
</script><noscript>Sorry, you need Javascript on to email me.</noscript>

Comment: Jaakko - I suggest moving the javascript into a separate .js file.  This should allow it to pass validation.

Comment: @Jaako Seppälä: It is better to edit your question, rather than posting in the comments. I have edited it for you. I will answer your question if enough people vote to re-open the question.

Comment: The OP is saying that on the page at the URL above, there is a valid mailto: link to his email address, but it's actually assembled client-side with javascript so that spambots can't scrape his address out of it. His problem is the code doesn't pass wc3's validator.

Comment: The basic answer is that in XHTML, it is not valid to put raw JavaScript in the source without putting it into a comment or a CDATA section. But all browsers are actually interpreting this as HTML, so it's working fine in the browsers. You probably would be to put an opening comment delimiter "<!--" in the script tag (you have a comment close, but not an open).

Comment: Brian, I admire your kindness (I really mean that). I don't agree with you though. It doesn't matter whether the OP is a newcomer or a veteran: the way the original question was worded: quite a few typos due to hastiness (in another place a misspelled word was correctly spelled) and the utter lack of information made me decide to vote for closure. I didn't epxect it to actually happen so soon though. Because of that, I will revoke that vote (vote for re-open) and leave this thread for those who are more patient.

Comment: The thing is, a newcomer doesn't necessarily know exactly how much detail to put in a question, and may be unfamiliar with how markdown and Stack Overflow work. A vote to close means that even if the question is fixed, people will have to vote to re-open the question can be answered. This question was closed within 5 minutes of the OP posting it; that's nowhere near enough time for the OP to read the comments, figure out how editing questions works, and fix the problem. I feel that a friendly comment pointing out that there isn't enough information is much more helpful than a close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue here is that you have a `<script>` tag that contains a `<` sign. The XHTML parser sees that as the beginning of a new tag, which it believes is called `coded.length`.

There are a few possible solutions. One is to put in the opening comment delimiter. You have the closing delimiter `-->`, but not the opening delimiter. You just have to add a line containing `<!--` right after the `<script>` to get this to work. When I try that on your page, though I get a validation error about the `<noscript>` element. `<noscript>` appears to have some serious problems in XHTML 1.1, I'm not sure how to get it to both work and validate.

Of course, you appear to be serving your XHTML with mime type `text/html`, which is technically incorrect, and which means that browsers actually parse it as HTML, not as XHTML. See [Sending XHTML as text/html Considered Harmful](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml) for some information on why this is a bad idea (though some of the reasons on that page are out of date, as they refer to old browsers that basically no one is using any more).

Another solution is to switch from an XHTML doctype to HTML5. This is a new, much easier to use doctype, that is more closely based on how browsers actually parse your HTML. All you have to do is change your `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM ...>` declaration to `<!DOCTYPE html>`. That's it! Well, you'll also have to remove your `</meta>` close tag, or turn it into a self closing element `<meta ... />`. In this case, you don't need the comments around the contents of the `<script>` element; the parser will ignore all `<` signs up to the next `</script>`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving the javascript into a separate .js file. This should allow the HTML to pass validation.  It is a good practice to have this separation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code does not validate is because inside `<script></script>` you must use HTML entitites to represent HTML chars like `<` `>` `&`

the parser complains about `<coded.length element not defined` because the validator is seeing a HTML tag there

The most simple option is to escape to HTML entities the content st the script tag, a better move is to have your JS at a different file, linked to your page